# How to remove duplicates in array of objects in reactJs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reactjs

I'm pushing on objects while clicking on button with Reactjs. Initially i'm having three type of objects like "LOCAL", "GLOBAL" and "MAIN". I'm passing these names as parameters in onclock callback. How to an avoid to insert duplicates with reactJs?

My render code,

```
<div>
   <input type="checkbox" onClick={this.checkedIn.bind(this, "LOCAL", "12")} />
   <button type="checkbox" onClick={this.checkedIn.bind(this, "GLOBAL", "15")} />
   <button type="checkbox" onClick={this.checkedIn.bind(this, "MAIN", "11")} />
  <button type="checkbox" onClick={this.checkedIn.bind(this, "MAIN", "13")} />
</div>
```

**onclick event**

```
var objectVale = [];
checkedIn(type, value) {
  objectVale.push({
    type:type,
    value:[value]
  })
}
```

Expecting output,

```
[
  {
    "type":"LOCAL",
    "value":[12]
  },
  {
    "type":"GLOBAL",
    "value":[15]
  },
  {
    "type":"MAIN",
    "value":[11, 13]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
var objectVale = [];
checkedIn(type, value) {

    var index = objectValue.findIndex(function(obj){ return obj.type === type; });
    if(index === -1){ // Object with the specific type not found.
        objectValue.push({
            type:type,
            value:[value]
        })
    } else { // Object with the specific type found. So push only the value.
        objectValue[index].value.push(value)
    }
}
```

Comment: Also I'd suggest using `.find`. This way you will not have to fetch object using index.

Comment: @Rajesh I would say that both ways are valid.

Comment: Also, if i uncheck that checkbox, the unchecked checked should be removed. I tried this way, var mainValues = []; mainValues.push(value); var sameValueIndex =  mainValues.indexOf(value); mainValues.splice(sameValueIndex, 1); But its not giving correct result

Answer (score 1):

Issue is you are pushing value for every click event. Instead, first lookup array and find the necessary object using `type` and then push value to this object's value array.

```js
var o = objectVale.find(function(x) {
  return x.type === type;
})

if (o) {
  o.value = o.value || [];
  o.value.push(value);
} else {
  objectVale.push({
    type: type,
    value: [value]
  })
}
```